# Передача массива структур в функцию

Tags: c++, массивы

VS ругается на присвоение внутри функции полю name значения. Ошибка: "выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением". Подскажите, как в этом случае нужно передавать массив структур? Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 10;

struct sub {
    char name[10];
    int marks[5];
};

struct students {
    char name[20], sername[20], fatherName[20];
    int course;
    char speciality[25];
    sub subject;
};


void SetDefaultInformation(students* mas)
{
    mas[0].name = "Иван";
    mas[0].sername = "Петров";
    mas[0].subject.marks[0] = 2;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    students mas[SIZE];
    SetDefaultInformation(mas);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: данная ошибка происходит из-за неправильного копирования строк. прочитайте про функцию [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/?kw=strcpy).

Comment: а еще лучше читать не про `strcpy`, а про `std::string`

Comment: Если вы пишете на C++, не пользуйтесь сишными структурами данных. Берите `std::string` вместо `char[]` и `std::vector` вместо массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массивы не имеют оператора присваивания. Вы только можете поэлементно копировать элементы из одного массива в другой. То есть вы можете присваивать друг другу элементы массивов, если те в свою очередь не являются массивами и имеют оператор присваивания.

В вашем случае следует использовать стандартную C функцию `std::strcpy` (или можно использовать `std::strncpy`), которая объявлена в заголовке `<cstring>`.

Например

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

//;;;
void SetDefaultInformation(students* mas)
{
    strcpy( mas[0].name, "Иван" );
    strcpy( mas[0].sername, "Петров" );
    mas[0].subject.marks[0]  = 2;
}
```

Для работы со строками переменной длины в C++ есть стандартный класс `std::string`, объявленный в заголовке `<string>`

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение!

Comment: @Vladislav Не за что.:)

Answer (score 0):

Как можно реализовать средствами C++ (проверено на Mac OS X):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "stdafx.h"
#elif __APPLE__
#include "TargetConditionals.h" // Для макроса TARGET_OS_MAC.
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Русский язык в консоли - штука нетривиальная. 
void setCyrillicOutput()
{
#ifdef _WIN32 // Для Windows.
    locale rus("rus_rus.866");
    wcout.imbue(rus);
#elif __APPLE__ && TARGET_OS_MAC // Для Mac OS X.
    locale rus("ru_RU");
    wcout.imbue(rus);
#else // Заглушка для других ОС.
#warning Cyrillic output not implemented!
#endif
}

struct Subject
{
    wstring name;
    vector<int> scores;
};

struct Student
{
    wstring firstName;
    wstring patronymic;
    wstring lastName;
    unsigned int year;
    wstring specialization;
    Subject subject;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Student> students;
    students.emplace_back(Student{L"Иван", L"Васильевич", L"Петров", 2015u, L"Вычислительная техника", {L"Дискретная математика", {2}}});
    setCyrillicOutput();
    wcout << students[0].firstName << ' ' << students[0].lastName << ", " << students[0].subject.name << ": " << students[0].subject.scores[0] << endl;

    // Выходим из программы. Если консоль закрывается - 
    // поставьте на следующей строке точку останова.
    return 0;
}
```