# Как передать структуру в функцию?

Tags: c++

```
struct purchases{
    int number_purchases; 
    string name_product; 
    string name_firm; 
    float date_purchases; 
    int payment_amount;
};

//

int main(){

purchases records[100];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: А как вы попробовали ее передать? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: void create_file(struct purchases records);

Comment: Я просто даже  не имею представления как она должна передаваться.

Comment: @Егор Мардеросов: Все правильно передано. В чем тогда проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Такс, смотри, воот ссылки полезные для тебя [1](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/peredacha-vsey-struktury-v-funkciyu),[2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458704/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E)

1) Передача всей структуры в функцию

```
void f1(struct purchases parm)
 {
    std::cout<< parm.number_purchases<<endl;
 }
```

2) Передача массива структур в функцию

```
 void SetDefaultInformation(struct purchases* records)
 {
    records[0].number_purchases  = 2;
 }
```

Применение:

```
 int main()
  {
     purchases records[100];

     SetDefaultInformation(records);

     system("pause");
     return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Purchases {
    int number_purchases;
    string name_product;
    string name_firm;
    float date_purchases;
    int payment_amount;
};

void foo(Purchases *p, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << p[i].date_purchases << endl 
             << p[i].name_firm << endl
             << p[i].name_product << endl
             << p[i].number_purchases << endl
             << p[i].payment_amount << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    const int LENGTH = 100;
    Purchases records[LENGTH];
    foo(records, LENGTH);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```